# how to get share point list item by Id in

Tags: development, sharepoint-list

i have sharepoint list , in which i get all data , now i want to update an item in sharepoint list , so i want to get by id and than update that list here is my code.
here i get nothing in olistitem

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://URL/"))
{
    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USername", "********");
    Web webObj = context.Web;
    List listObj = webObj.Lists.GetByTitle("Leave Requests");
    CamlQuery camlquery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(10);
    ListItemCollection listitemcoll = listObj.GetItems(camlquery);
    context.Load(listitemcoll);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    ListItem oListItem = listObj.GetItemById(186);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to update a specific list item by id. You really dont have to get all list items(unless you want to do something like display them later) before updating a list item.

```
        string siteUrl = "http://servername:2525/";  
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);  
        List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestList");  
        ListItem oListItem = oList.GetItemById(5);  
        oListItem["Title"] = "Hello World Updated!!!";  
        oListItem.Update();  
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: Thats great Razim !

Answer (score 0):

In Client object model you need to create your query, load object and execute query for getting result.

In above code, you just query to SharePoint but not execute that query.

Please use below code:

```
 using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://URL/"))
                                {
                                    context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                                    context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USername", "********");
                                    Web webObj = context.Web;
                                    List listObj = webObj.Lists.GetByTitle("Leave Requests");
                                    CamlQuery camlquery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery(10);
                                    ListItemCollection listitemcoll = listObj.GetItems(camlquery);
                                    context.Load(listitemcoll);
                                    context.ExecuteQuery();

                                    ListItem oListItem = listObj.GetItemById(186);
context.Load(oListItem);
                                    context.ExecuteQuery();


                                }
```